# Indexing in nested loops

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I am new to R and this site. My aim with the following, assuredly unnecessarily-arcane code is to create an R function that produces a special type of box plot in ggplot2. I first need to process potential input thereinto by calculating the variables that I shall later wish to have plotted.

I start by generating some random data, called `datos`:

```
c1=rnorm(98,47,23)
c2=rnorm(98,56,13)
c3=rnorm(98,52,7)
fila1=as.matrix(t(c(-2,15,30)))
colnames(fila1)=c("c1","c2","c3")
fila2=as.matrix(t(c(-20,5,20)))
colnames(fila2)=c("c1","c2","c3")
datos=rbind(data.frame(c1,c2,c3),fila1,fila2)
rm(c1,c2,c3,fila1,fila2)
```

Then, I calculate the variables to later be plotted, which include for each of the present columns in `datos` the mean (`puntoMedio`), the first and third quartiles (`cuar1`,`cuar3`), the inner-quartile range (`iqr`), the lower bound of potential submean whiskers (`limInf`), the upper bound of potential supermean whiskers (`limSup`) and outliers (submean outliers `vAtInf` and supermean outliers `vAtSup` to be combined in `vAt`):

```
puntoMedio=apply(datos,MARGIN=2,FUN=mean)
cuar1=apply(datos,MARGIN=2,FUN=quantile,probs=.25)
cuar3=apply(datos,MARGIN=2,FUN=quantile,probs=.75)
cuar=rbind(cuar1,cuar3)
iqr=apply(cuar,MARGIN=2,FUN=diff)
cuar=rbind(cuar,iqr,puntoMedio)
limInf=array(dim=ncol(datos))
  for(i in 1:ncol(datos)){
    limInf0=as.matrix(t(cuar[1,]-1.5*cuar[3,]))
    if(length(datos[datos[,i]<limInf0[,i],i])>0){
      limInf[i]=limInf0[,i]
    }else{limInf[i]=min(datos[,i])}
  }
limSup=array(dim=ncol(datos))
  for(i in 1:ncol(datos)){
    limSup0=as.matrix(t(cuar[2,]+1.5*cuar[3,]))
    if(length(datos[datos[,i]>limSup0[,i],i])>0){
      limSup[i]=limSup0[,i]
    }else{limSup[i]=max(datos[,i])}
  }
d=data.frame(t(rbind(cuar,limInf,limSup)))
rm(cuar)
vAtInf=datos
  for(i in 1:ncol(vAtInf)){
    vAtInf[vAtInf[,i]>limInf0[,i],i]=NA
  }
  colnames(vAtInf)=c("vAtInfc1","vAtInfc2","vAtInfc3")
vAtSup=datos
  for(i in 1:ncol(vAtSup)){
    vAtSup[vAtSup[,i]<limSup0[,i],i]=NA
  }
  colnames(vAtSup)=c("vAtSupc1","vAtSupc2","vAtSupc3")
datos=cbind(datos,vAtInf,vAtSup)
rm(limInf0,limSup0,cuar1,cuar3,i,iqr,limInf,limSup,puntoMedio)
```

Everything works as desired up until here. I have two data frames `d` and `datos`, the former of no interest here, and the latter, which in this specific case comprises nine columns: three of all values, three of the corresponding submean outliers and three of the corresponding supermean outliers (these latter six padded with NA). I now wish to extract all outliers by column, wherefore I have tried formulating the following loop. While it does work giving neither error nor warning, it also does not give the desired output in `vAt` (again, the by-column [columns 4:9] outliers from `datos`). The problem, then, as far as I have been able to discern, occurs in the nested for-loop, upon attempting to input `i` into `vAt`: each iteration of the loop erases the last, such that upon completion of the entire loop, `vAt` only contains NA and the outliers from the last column/of the last iteration.

```
for(i in ((ncol(datos)/3)+1):ncol(datos)){
    vAt=matrix(nrow=.25*nrow(datos),ncol=ncol(datos)-(ncol(datos)/3))
    colnames(vAt)=c(((ncol(datos)/3)+1):ncol(datos))
    if(length(datos[,i][is.na(datos[,i])==F])>0){
        for(j in 1:(length(datos[,i][is.na(datos[,i])==F]))){
            nom=as.character(i)
            vAt[j,nom]=datos[,i][is.na(datos[,i])==F][j]
        }
    }else{next}
}
```

I have not been able to find any [existent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-loop+indexing+r) that answers my question. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are initialising `vAt` inside the loop here.
Moving the initialisation statements outside the `for` loop will fix the problem that you are facing:

```
vAt=matrix(nrow=.25*nrow(datos),ncol=ncol(datos)-(ncol(datos)/3))
colnames(vAt)=c(((ncol(datos)/3)+1):ncol(datos))
for(i in ((ncol(datos)/3)+1):ncol(datos)){
    if(length(datos[,i][is.na(datos[,i])==F])>0){
        for(j in 1:(length(datos[,i][is.na(datos[,i])==F]))){
            nom=as.character(i)
            vAt[j,nom]=datos[,i][is.na(datos[,i])==F][j]
        }
    }else{next}
}
```

However, there are various improvements which you can make to the code as it stands:

1. Using `vectorisation` and `*ply` functions instead of `for` loops.
2. Not comparing logical vectors to `==F` but instead only using `!is.na(...)`.
3. Using `sum(is.na(...))` instead of `length(d[,i][!is.na(...)])`

And some more. These will not change the correctness of the code, but will make it more efficient and more idiomatic.