# R nested loop returning only the last iteration

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to replicate 81-place cryoboxes used in lab storage system using a **nested for loop**. The following code illustrates the problem using 3-place boxes:

```
urine_random_df <- as.data.frame(c(seq(from = 10, to = 12, by = 1)))
boxcells <- vector()
cell_placeholder <- as.data.frame(c(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1)))
for (i in 1: 3){
        #boxcells <- paste0("NEW", sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(urine_random_df[i,])))
        for (j in 1: nrow(cell_placeholder)){
                boxcells <- c(boxcells, paste(paste0("NEW", sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(urine_random_df[i,]))), cell_placeholder[j,], sep = "-"))        
        }

}


boxcells <- data.frame(boxcells)
names(boxcells) <- "box cells"
boxcells
```

The result of above is:

```
box cells
1 NEW0010-1
2 NEW0010-2
3 NEW0010-3
4 NEW0011-1
5 NEW0011-2
6 NEW0011-3
7 NEW0012-1
8 NEW0012-2
9 NEW0012-3
```

However, I would like to group the cells under their respective boxes like so:

```
   box cells
1  NEW0010
2  NEW0010-1
3  NEW0010-2
3  NEW0010-3
4  NEW0011
5  NEW0011-1
6  NEW0011-2
7  NEW0011-3
8  NEW0012
9  NEW0012-1
10 NEW0012-2
11 NEW0012-3
```

I tried to achieve this by adding `boxcells <- paste0("NEW", sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(urine_random_df[i,])))` in the outer loop. When I re-ran the code with this piece, I get only the last box like so:

```
  box cells
1   NEW0012
2 NEW0012-1
3 NEW0012-2
4 NEW0012-3
```

It appears each iteration of the loop erases the last such that upon completion of the entire loop, only the last box remains. I found an [existing thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822459/indexing-in-nested-loops) which suggests moving the "initialisation statements" outside the loop. However, in this case, the initialisation statements `urine_random_df...`, `boxcells...` and `cell_placeholder...` are already outside the loop. Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want such output? you can use such result for further processing. Either you need your result in a list or in a  data.frame with 2 columns ( id , value).

Comment: @sedeh, why wouldn't you consider doing it the way I proposed? why are you trying to stick with nested `for` loops which are very inefficient in R?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think you are right. Your code seem to work well. I am trying to understand what is going on in the code and may select it as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of very rare situations when you would do a nested `for` loop in R, even single `for` loop is very rare.

I would solve this by doing something like

```
temp <- expand.grid(sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(urine_random_df[,1])), c("", paste0("-",cell_placeholder[, 1])))
boxcells <- data.frame(box_cells = paste0("NEW", paste0(temp[, 1], temp[, 2])))
```

Which will return

```
   box_cells
1    NEW0010
2    NEW0011
3    NEW0012
4  NEW0010-1
5  NEW0011-1
6  NEW0012-1
7  NEW0010-2
8  NEW0011-2
9  NEW0012-2
10 NEW0010-3
11 NEW0011-3
12 NEW0012-3
```

If you don't like the order, you could reorder by

```
boxcells <- data.frame(box_cells = boxcells[order(as.numeric(substr(boxcells$box_cells, 6,7))), ])

   box_cells
1    NEW0010
2  NEW0010-1
3  NEW0010-2
4  NEW0010-3
5    NEW0011
6  NEW0011-1
7  NEW0011-2
8  NEW0011-3
9    NEW0012
10 NEW0012-1
11 NEW0012-2
12 NEW0012-3
```

Comment: `dplyr`'s `arrange()` will also work on the first `boxcells` data frame: `arrange(boxcells, box_cells)`.

Comment: @KaraWoo Almost but not quite. Here's a snippet of the ordering with dplyr: `2211  NEW0036-8
2212 NEW0036-80
2213 NEW0036-81
2214  NEW0036-9`. This is as applied to my larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I think the complication here comes from collecting the output of the loop as a vector rather than a list.

Here it is using a list, then unlisting and converting to a dataframe. The output is exactly as requested

```
urine_random_df <- as.data.frame(c(seq(from = 10, to = 12, by = 1)))
boxcells <- list()
cell_placeholder <- as.data.frame(c(seq(from = 1, to = 3, by = 1)))
n <- nrow(cell_placeholder)
for (i in 1:n){
  tmp <- vector()
tmp <- c(paste0("NEW", sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(urine_random_df[i,]))))
      for (j in 1:n){
        tmp <- c(tmp, paste(paste0("NEW", sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(urine_random_df[i,]))), cell_placeholder[j,], sep = "-"))        
      }
      boxcells[[i]] <- tmp 
}


boxcells <- data.frame(unlist(boxcells))
names(boxcells) <- "box cells"
boxcells
```

Which gives:

```
 box cells
1    NEW0010
2  NEW0010-1
3  NEW0010-2
4  NEW0010-3
5    NEW0011
6  NEW0011-1
7  NEW0011-2
8  NEW0011-3
9    NEW0012
10 NEW0012-1
11 NEW0012-2
12 NEW0012-3
```

Comment: Maybe this answer the question , but you should now that doing something like `tmp <- c(tmp,..)` inside a `for` loop is very bad practice in R( very slow + side effect)

Comment: Yes I know, a very reasonable comment. I simply propose the method that is the closest to the OP's attempt and gives the result they say they want. Maybe it will be easier for them to understand and then continue to optimise from there, and maybe they have reasons that limit them to the way they describe.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. I wonder if there is a way to improve or rework Ben's code to get away from the side effect.

Comment: Might be best to give some upvotes all round, choose the best answer, then ask for optimisation suggestions in a new question and refer back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group result better to choose another structure to store your result. Here 2 ways to simply resolve your problem:

```
nn <- paste0('NEW',sprintf("%04d",10:12))
```

#### using a list

```
setNames(lapply(nn,function(x){
  paste(x,1:3,sep='-')
}),nn)

$NEW0010
[1] "NEW0010-1" "NEW0010-2" "NEW0010-3"

$NEW0011
[1] "NEW0011-1" "NEW0011-2" "NEW0011-3"

$NEW0012
[1] "NEW0012-1" "NEW0012-2" "NEW0012-3"
```

#### using data.frame

```
transform(expand.grid(nn,1:3),Var2=paste(Var1,Var2,sep='-'))

     Var1      Var2
1 NEW0010 NEW0010-1
2 NEW0011 NEW0011-1
3 NEW0012 NEW0012-1
4 NEW0010 NEW0010-2
5 NEW0011 NEW0011-2
6 NEW0012 NEW0012-2
7 NEW0010 NEW0010-3
8 NEW0011 NEW0011-3
9 NEW0012 NEW0012-3
```

Comment: This may be a solution to the problem, but it is not an answer to the question :) Well, let's see what the OP thinks is more important (and how good your mind-reading powers are!)

Comment: @Ben I am not here to give a solution (no offence) , but to show the best R way to solve a problem.

Comment: @agstudy Your suggestion is creative. However, I require a strict format in the output. I think Ben and I are on the same train of thought although I now need to worry about the slowness of `tmp <- c(tmp,..)`. Anyway to get around `tmp <- c(tmp,..)`?